# Unit test verify method was called inside RxJava's doOnSuccess operator

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, rx-java2

I have the following code I'm trying to unit test :

```
    if (networkUtils.isOnline()) {
        return remoteDataSource.postComment(postId, commentText)
                .doOnSuccess(postCommentResponse ->
                        localDataSource.postComment(postId, commentText))
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                .observeOn(schedulerProvider.mainThread());
    } else {
        return Single.error(new IOException());
    }
```

And this is how I'm trying to test it :

```
@Test
public void postComment_whenIsOnline_shouldCallLocalToPostComment() throws Exception {
    // Given
    when(networkUtils.isOnline())
            .thenReturn(true);
    String postId = "100";
    String comment = "comment";

    Response<PostCommentResponse> response = postCommentResponse();
    when(remoteDataSource.postComment(anyString(), anyString()))
            .thenReturn(Single.just(response));

    // When
    repository.postComment(postId, comment);

    // Then
    verify(localDataSource).postComment(postId, comment);
}
```

where I fake Response from Retrofit like :

```
private Response<PostCommentResponse> postCommentResponse() {
    PostCommentResponse response = new PostCommentResponse();
    response.setError("0");
    response.setComment(postCommentResponseNestedItem);

    return Response.success(response);
}
```

but it results to : `Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

Any ideas ?

EDIT :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CommentsRepositoryTest {

@Mock
private CommentsLocalDataSource localDataSource;

@Mock
private CommentsRemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;

@Mock
private NetworkUtils networkUtils;

@Mock
private PostCommentResponseNestedItem postCommentResponseNestedItem;

private CommentsRepository repository;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    BaseSchedulerProvider schedulerProvider = new ImmediateSchedulerProvider();

    repository = new CommentsRepository(localDataSource, remoteDataSource, networkUtils, schedulerProvider);
}


   // tests


}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `repository` has a reference of `remoteDataSource` to which is delegating the `postComment` action?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The code is working as expected (meaning that when I post a comment I can then find it in the database)

Comment: Yes, but I don't expect the database to be affected while testing. I don't know what's wrong, but I suspect that some or your mocked components are not injected. Like `networkUtils` or `remoteDataSource`.

Comment: @GVillani82 I  have edited the question with some code from the test class in case it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to test an `Observable` you have to subscribe to it so it will start emitting items.

As soon as I used :

```
TestObserver<Response<PostCommentResponse>> testObserver = new TestObserver<>();
```

and subscribed to :

```
    repository.postComment(postId, comment)
            .subscribe(testObserver);
```

the test worked as expected.